# Angular 2 - invoke function if JQuery selector :visible of a DOM element changes

Tags: jquery, html, css, angular, typescript

I have a  element with an CSS 'background-image' and want to listen to the visibility of that element in an Angular 2 project. If the visibility changes, I want to invoke a function. I've tried it with (ngModelChange) in my  element, but the function was not invoked, when the visibility changes.
Is there another way to achieve this?

```
<span (ngModelChange)="doSomething($event)" class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
```

Comment: What do you mean by visibility ? Did you create an output (ngModelChange) because it is not a native event handler comparing to (click) (change)

Comment: are u controlling the visibility of parent element of `span` using `ngIf` or `hidden` ?

Comment: With visibility I mean, a true value of the jQuery selector ':visible':  $(".navbar-toggler-icon").is(":visible");

Comment: Actually I'm using a bootstrap navbar and want to check when the navbar-toggler-icon is visible. So the visibility is controlled by bootstrap. <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark mb-4">
 <button id="navbar-toggler-btn" class="navbar-toggler" (click)="togglerSetIsCollapsed()" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
<span (ngModelChange)="doSomething($event)" class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button></div>